# bind not saving value as expected

Tags: javascript

```
var trackDay = new Date(2013, 10, 1);


alert(trackDay);

img.addEventListener("click", function(trackDay){                            
    alert(trackDay);
}.bind(null,trackDay),true); 

trackDay.setDate(trackDay.getDate()+1);
```

This alert on the click event produces the value for the incremented date when I want it to be the first value.

Comment: Looks to be working as expected.

Comment: Your code doesn't alert 1: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezJBGcbEo6Pvj54Ifuhb?p=info)

Comment: See edited version, the problem is when using setDate.

Comment: That's because objects are passed by reference in JavaScript. If all you want inside the event listener is the string representation then you can pass `trackDay.toString()` as an argument in the bind method.

Comment: I need to have it still as an object for more processing as date.

Comment: This looks to difficult to do so I am just going to pass, the relevant properties of the date object that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you cannot / don't want to use a second variable than you can pass the string representation of the date object with bind and create a new date object out of that string inside your callback function.

[Check the plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ezJBGcbEo6Pvj54Ifuhb)

```
var trackDay = new Date(2013, 10, 1);

alert(trackDay);

img.addEventListener("click", function(trackDay){
    var date = new Date(trackDay);
    alert(date);
}.bind(null,trackDay.toString()),true); 

trackDay.setDate(trackDay.getDate()+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameslafferty/MwLpv/) do what you want?

Html:

```
<img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
```

JavaScript:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var img;
    function trackDay (val) {
        return function () {
            alert(val);
            val += 1;
        }
    }
    img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    img.addEventListener("click", trackDay(0), true);
}());
```